# Pandas append a new line in loop: not appended and no error

Tags: python, pandas

I'm writing a script to extract features from txt files. 
I created a first dataframe containing the column names I need. 
And then, I loop through all the files in the folder, and extract the features needed. 
I then create a new dataframe that is a single line, and append it to the "features" dataframe.

I get no error, but the "features" dataframe stays empty. 
I'm a bit confused about the index when creating a df as I think the error can come from there. But what if you don't know it? or don't want to iterate the index when appending?
Isn't there a way to just "add" the lines, like the collections in Java (Arraylist etc)?

```
#we create a df that will contain the chosen features
features = pd.DataFrame(columns = 
{
"salary_start",
"salary_end",
"open date",
"requirements",
"duties",
"deadline",
"selection"
})

for file_name in list_of_files:
    header = []
    try:
        f = open(path_to_plain_txt + file_name, "r")
        file = f.read().replace('\t', '')
        text = file.replace('\n', '')

        headers = [head for head in file.split("\n") if head.isupper()] 

        #since I'm using a utils file, there's no confusion between re 
        variables and the csv. 
        salare = re.search(utils.salary, text)
        date = datetime.strptime(re.search(utils.opendate, text).group(3), 
        '%m-%d-%y')

        duties = re.search(utils.duties, text).group(2)
        try:
            requirements = re.search(utils.requirements, text).group(2)
        except Exception as e:
            requirements = 
            re.search('(.*)NOTES?',re.findall(r'(REQUIREMENTS?)(.*) 
            (NOTES?)',text)[0][1][:1200]).group(1)
        try:
            enddate = datetime.strptime(re.search(re.enddate,text).group(), 
            '%m-%d-%y')
        except Exception as e:
            enddate = np.nan

        selection = [z[0] for z in re.findall('([A-Z][a-z]+)((\s\.\s)+)', 
                    text)]
        line = pd.DataFrame({'salary_start': [salare.group(1)],
                    'salara_end': [salare.group(5)], 
                    'open date': [date],
                    'requirements': [requirements],
                    'duties': [duties], 
                    'deadline': [enddate],
                    'selection': [selection]
    })
        features.append(line, ignore_index = True)

        #and now we write everything in the CSV

    except Exception as e:
       print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem.
So I learned two things from this:

1- Collections don't work the same way from different languages => no assumption!

2- Re reading the documentation multiple times is never a waste of time.

Pandas documention says:

> Append rows of other to the end of caller, **returning a new object**.

To make my code work, I had to do this:

```
features = features.append(line, ignore_index = True)
```